# Gostaria de saber como se resolve esse exercício - Vetores no Visualg

Tags: array, visualg, portugol

72. Crie um programa que preencha automaticamente (usando lógica, não apenas
    atribuindo diretamente) um vetor numérico com 10 posições, conforme abaixo:

5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50

0         1     2    3      4    5      6     7    8   9

[imagem do exercício para melhor visualização](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU604.png)

```
algoritmo "semnome"
var
c, n: inteiro
v: vetor[0..9] de inteiro
inicio

     para c <- 5 ate 50 passo 5 faca
       escreva("[",c:1,"]")
     fimpara
     escreval("")
     
      escreva("")
     para n <- 0 ate 9 faca
          escreva(n,"  ")
     fimpara
 fimalgoritmo
```

Dessa forma o programa deu certo mas não consegui chamar o vetor pq sempre fica zerado

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: De acordo com o enunciado "Crie um programa que preencha automaticamente (usando lógica, não apenas atribuindo diretamente) um vetor numérico com 10 posições, conforme abaixo:" Peço para que olhe a imagem que eu anexei pra melhor visualização do problema.
 No entanto, eu não conseguir chamar o vetor e quando eu tentava chamar os números abaixo (1,2 3...) ficavam zerado

Answer (score -2):

[Imagem com o código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVDQp.png)

Só multiplicar n por 5, com ele indo de 1 a 10, assim você vai ter 10 posições de vetores com os valores que estão na imagem do exercício.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Basta fazer o seguinte
Explicação:

C que começa com zero, recebe + 1 e é multiplicado por 5 = 5

já no segundo ciclo, C já é 1, com + 1 e multiplicado por 5, fica = 10. E assim por diante.

Var

V: vetor [0..9] de inteiro

C:inteiro

Inicio

```
 Para C <- 0 Ate 9 Faca
    V[C] <- (C + 1) * 5
 FimPara
 
 Para C <- 0 ate 9 faca
   Escreva (V[C])
 FimPara
```

Fimalgoritmo